# Firebase Google Sign-In doesn't work after reset of the key certificate by Google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console, android-keystore

I had lost my upload-key so I asked google to reinitialize it, they did it and now I can't sign-in anymore with Google Account (no problem before that), status code 10 so it isn't normally the code the problem.

I use Firebase Google Sign-In.

- I update SHA in Firebase (and update the google-services.Json in my app).
- I update my Web Client credential in Firebase and in my code.
- I invalidate cache/restart and clean the project.
- OAuth consent is accepted.
- SHA-1 is the same in play.google.com and Firebase, and the app is signed with it (no problem to upload apk in Google Play Console, same sign-in problem when I use the app downloaded from intern test).

Any idea what I could have forgotten?

Email received from google : 
"Good news - I was able to register a new upload key for your app, irlove.com.irl. Make sure to update your keystores in the following locations:

Local machine

Locked on-site server (varying ACLs)

Cloud machine (varying ACLs)

Dedicated secrets management services

(git) repos"

I don't really know what I have to do to "update my keystores in the following location". Just know that I don't have git repos.

Comment: Which APK doesn't work: the one signed with your upload key or the one that Google has re-signed?

Comment: Same for both, when I launch it on emulator from Android Studio doesn't work, when I download it from intern test doesn't work neither.

Comment: Did you also update the sha1 in the Google Developer console, in the API Credentials?

Comment: In "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" I have "Android client (auto created by Google Service)" with the upload-SHA1 (and one with debug sha1, sign-in in debug APK works now, I just stupidly deleted the debug sha1 from firebase, I re-added it and it works, everything is the same for upload sha1 so this sign-in bug in upload apk puzzles me even more now ^^').

Comment: Did you also add the sha1 of the app signing key (i.e. the key Play re-signs the APK with)? You can find it in the App Signing page of the Play Console.

Comment: Yes it is the "upload key" in "import certificate" of Play console (set by google).

Comment: The upload key is not the key that Play uses to sign APK, that the key that *you* use to sign your APK/AAB that you upload to the Play Console. IIUC, you have whitelisted the upload certificate, but not the app signing certificate. Both certificates can be found the App Signing page of the Play Console.

Comment: God dam' THANK YOU !!! 
Since my app was only "published" for internal testing, I didn't realize it was already taken into account.

It works !

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add also the old App Signing SHA1 into Firebase, so both and the new one were included (along with Update Key SHA1 and debug.keystore SHA1). Otherwise it wouldn't work once the app is served from Play Store.